# Combination with repetition and no order.

Tags: combinatorics

I'm looking for a way to calculate the number of combination of 10 choose 5 => $_5^{10}C$ while allowing any number repetitions and counting `12345` and `54321` only once (order isn't important, ie I count 11355 but not then 35115).

I think this number is majored by $10^5$, but how to remove ordering number ?

Comment: Would it be just $\left(\begin{array}{c}50\\5\end{array}\right)$?

Comment: Does "allowing any number repetitions" mean you're including, for example, 11355 (but not then also 35153)?

Comment: Check "combinations with repetitions" http://users.telenet.be/vdmoortel/dirk/Maths/PermVarComb.html

Comment: @aPaulT I accept both. But I include 11355 but no then 35115 (you may make a mistake on your example)

Comment: @EpicGuy Are you sure ? I thought it should be lower than $10^5$

Comment: @Fractaliste Well isn't just choosing 5 numbers from the set: $1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,...,10,10,10,10,10$?

Comment: @SJuan76 That's an interesting table to know, thanks !

Comment: Quite right Fractaliste, I did mess up my example. @EpicGuy Your method, for example, counts '11112' twenty-five times (because it counts each of the ways of picking four of the five 1s in your list separately, and for each of those it then counts the five ways of picking one of the five 2s).

Comment: @EpicGuy : it's an interesting way to understand the problem, but the result is far over the expected result. And I'm not able to see the mistake (if there is one). I'm going to think about it !

Comment: Such counting of multisets is possible by the standard "stars-and-bars" method, c.f. the duplicate [How to find unique multisets of n naturals of a given domain and their numbers?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/17083/how-to-find-unique-multisets-of-n-naturals-of-a-given-domain-and-their-numbers)

Comment: @EpicGuy: this is wrong. Notice that you're counting $5,5,5,5,4$ 25 times, for instance.

Comment: @tomasz I am using combinations and I don't get how you got 25 times.

Comment: @EpicGuy: you have 5 copies of $5$ and 5 copies of $4$. So you can draw $\{5,5,5,5,4\}$ in $\binom 5 4\cdot \binom 5 1$ ways.

Comment: ok I realise my mistake thanks for pointing it out

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(Note: I'm using the notation $\binom{n}{k}$ here instead of $^n_kC$.)

A multiset is a collection of things that allows repetition but ignores order. The [number of multisets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset#Counting_multisets) of size $k$ with elements from a set of size $n$ is

$$\left(\!\!\binom{n}{k}\!\!\right) = \binom{n+k-1}{k} = \frac{(n+k-1)!}{k! (n-1)!}.$$

In your case, you'll have $\left(\!\!\binom{10}{5}\!\!\right) = \binom{10+5-1}{5} = 2002$.

Comment: The answer $\binom{14}{5}$ is given by [the standard "stars-and-bars" method](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/17083/3111).  Arrange nine "bars" (separators) and five "stars" (placeholders for elements of multisets) in a line.  Any items to the left of the first bar are counted as zeros; items between the ith and i+1st bar are counted as i's; items after the ninth bar are 9's.

Answer (score 1):

Since order doesn't matter, we can consider results as different if they differ after sorting.
In other words, when order doesn't matter, generate the results with inherent sorting.
If you build a table, 5 slots wide and 10 slots high, and trace all paths from bottom left to somewhere on the right edge, but only allow paths to go 1 step right and never go down, then a clear pattern emerges. The right hand side of this tabel contains 1,5,15,35.. or (n+3) choose 4. The sum at the right edge is 2002 or 14 ch 5.
The diagonals are Pascal's triangle.